# Alternative to 'тотчас же'

Tags: выбор-слова, синонимы, словоупотребление

What is an alternative way to say 'тотчас же?' Maybe it is not really in use anymore, but it keeps popping up in Russian literature I'm reading, and it's a bit hard to get out sometimes. What is a more modern way to say 'at once/immediately'? Сразу?

Comment: тут же is what u need

Answer (score 5):

That expression is mainly used in literature; probably "**тут же**" is its closest version in everyday speech. While it literally means '*right here*' it marks the immediate point in both space and time. Other expressions for specific cases of action include: "сразу же", "сходу", "не мешкая", "не долго думая", "спешно", "в ту же минуту", "через мгновение"и т. п.

Answer (score 3):

You can also say "**сейчас же**", "**немедленно**", "**в мгновение ока**", and, as you suggested, "**сразу [же]**".

The difference between "**тотчас**" and, say, "**сейчас**", is that "**тотчас**" refers to "**тот**" "**час**", that is, "**that hour**" ("**that time**"), where as "**сейчас**" refers to "**сей час**", or "**this hour**" ("**this time**").

Answer (score 1):

Не заглядывая в словари, могу сказать, что **тотчас же** это абсолютно книжное выражение и в разговорной речи практически не употребляется. В разговорной речи употребляются чаще всего такие "аналоги" этого выражения, как **сейчас же**и **сразу же.**

Not looking in dictionaries, I can say that **тотчас же** this brand book expression in colloquial speech is not used practically. In colloquial speech used most often such "analogues" of this expression, **сейчас же** and **сразу же**.